# concatenate columns of matrix into one vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

suppose that we have following two random matrix

```
x=rand(7,7);

x

x =

    0.8147    0.5469    0.8003    0.0357    0.6555    0.8235    0.7655
    0.9058    0.9575    0.1419    0.8491    0.1712    0.6948    0.7952
    0.1270    0.9649    0.4218    0.9340    0.7060    0.3171    0.1869
    0.9134    0.1576    0.9157    0.6787    0.0318    0.9502    0.4898
    0.6324    0.9706    0.7922    0.7577    0.2769    0.0344    0.4456
    0.0975    0.9572    0.9595    0.7431    0.0462    0.4387    0.6463
    0.2785    0.4854    0.6557    0.3922    0.0971    0.3816    0.7094
```

and

```
y=rand(6,5)

y =

    0.7547    0.4984    0.2551    0.1386    0.2435
    0.2760    0.9597    0.5060    0.1493    0.9293
    0.6797    0.3404    0.6991    0.2575    0.3500
    0.6551    0.5853    0.8909    0.8407    0.1966
    0.1626    0.2238    0.9593    0.2543    0.2511
    0.1190    0.7513    0.5472    0.8143    0.6160
```

i want to concatenate first four columns of each matrix into single one dimensional vector  c,i have tried

```
c=[x(:,4) y(:,4)]
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

but get following  error,please help me to  solve this problem

Comment: Use this instead: `c=[x(:,1:4); y(:,1:4)]; c(:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ reshape(x(:,1:4),[],1); reshape(y(:,1:4),[],1) ]
```

This stacks one column below the other: first those of `x` and then those of `y`. I guess that's the element order you want. (If you want to interleave one column of `x`, then one of `y` etc, see @RobertP's comment.)